# How to access the __str__ method of a model via a ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I have created a File model and a Folder model. The File model is connected to the Owner (User) and a Folder via a Foreign key. 
Now I want to upload the file at the path: `owner_username/folder_title`. My question is how to access the `__str__`method of the `Folder` model using the `ForeignKey`, from inside the File Model ?

My guess was to set at the `FileField` the argument upload_to equal to`str(folder)`but as a result my file was uploaded at:`<django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey>/graph2.jpg`

at models.py:

```
class Folder(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class File(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user', 
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    folder = models.ForeignKey(Folder, related_name = 'files', 
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    file = models.FileField(upload_to = !!!!?ownername/foldername?!!!!)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.file)
```

I expect somehow to upload the file at the path that has the following format: nameOfTheOwner/nameOfTheFolder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make set the [**`upload_to=`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) to a callable that has access to the `self`, like:

```
class File(models.Model):

    def gen_filename(self, filename):
        return '{}/{}/{}'.format(self.owner.username, self.folder.title, filename)

    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='user', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    folder = models.ForeignKey(
        Folder,
        related_name='files', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default=''
    )
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=gen_filename)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.file)
```

or you can make use of the `__str__` of the folder, like:

```
class File(models.Model):

    def gen_filename(self, filename):
        return '{}/{}/'.format(self.owner.username, self.folder, filename)

    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='user', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    folder = models.ForeignKey(
        Folder,
        related_name='files', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default=''
    )
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=gen_filename)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.file)
```

Comment: Thank you, both ideas are great and the first worked great with two corrections:
1) `gen_filename` returns `'{}/{}/{}'.format(self.owner.username, self.folder.title, filename)`
2)`FileField(upload_to = gen_filename)`